# No OpenID endpoint found - Relying Party Timeout Option

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I have a Relying Party and a provider running with DotNetOpenAuth.  The issue is that when the provider has not been accessed in a while it is unloaded from IIS to conserve memory (which is normally a good thing).  However, in this case it causes the Relying Party to throw the "No OpenID endpoint found" exception.

I know that IIS can be configured to never unload an application, but that is not an option in this case.

Is there a way to increase the timeout on the relying party to let it wait until the provider "wakes up" and not throw the No OpenId Endpoint Found exception?.

I thought I had it with the "maxAuthenticationTime" property, but I guess this is really a setting for how many minutes in total the authentication round trip should be allowed to take.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these timeouts can be configured via your web.config file.  Below is a snippet, with the defaults which you can raise:

```
   <messaging>
        <untrustedWebRequest
            timeout="00:00:10"
            readWriteTimeout="00:00:01.500"
```

[Full configuration options are documented](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/configuration-options/).

Comment: Ahh, ok, thanks.  That looks like it should do it, I hope.  Is there any place that actually describes what each of the keys does?  Just by looking at it I would have assumed that this timeout only applies to requests that result in the "This relying party is not trusted" warning on the confirm.aspx page (something like that I don't remember the exact error) because this is where all the whitelist/blacklist stuff goes too.  
  
But I guess not, this applies to all requests, or maybe "unauthenticated requests"?

Comment: It applies to all requests.  You get Intellisense in VS for these settings if you copy the .xsd that is included in DNOA's .zip file to the appropriate place, per the readme file.