# Troubleshooting intermittent "No OpenID endpoint found" messages with Google and DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, dotnetopenauth

I've been troubleshooting this one off and on for the past week.  I've got a site using relying party MVC code from the DotNetOpenAuth project.  I've been using this since 2009.

Recently, the Google logins have been failing.  I'd say about 80% of the time the Google login works fine.  So the intermittent nature makes this hard to diagnose.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Of course I've verified that the `openid_identifier` is using the correct URL ( https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id )
2. I've updated to the latest release (DotNetOpenAuth 3.4).
3. I've tried adding default proxy settings as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588502/no-openid-endpoint-found-net-openid).
4. I've extended the timeout settings and even reduced memory on SQL to give IIS more RAM as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904426/no-openid-endpoint-found-relying-party-timeout-option) suggests.
5. I've added logging to every request and error to see if I could get any valuable information.  This doesn't tell me much.
6. I've watched the requests/responses with Fiddler to see if I could spot anything.
7. I've tested my Google login on StackOverflow a number of times on the off chance that this is actually a problem with Google.  And it's been working every time so far.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

In effort to pinpoint the problem I changed the code on my site a bit.  Rather than doing this all on one line...

```
openid.CreateRequest(Request.Form["openid_identifier"]).RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
```

I broke it up into sections with logging in between...

```
MvcApplication.Logger.Info("Loading... " + Request.Form["openid_identifier"]);
var request = openid.CreateRequest(Request.Form["openid_identifier"]);
var redirect = request.RedirectingResponse;
MvcApplication.Logger.Info("Status... " + redirect.Status);
if (redirect.Status.ToString().ToLower() != "found")
{
    MvcApplication.Logger.Error("Details... " + redirect.Body);
}
return redirect.AsActionResult();
```

So I'll be waiting for the next error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  This was being caused by New Relic.  I'm not sure exactly how (or why it was intermittent) but that's what it was.  New Relic automatically instruments your pages in certain ways so maybe it interfered with the request to the OpenID provider.

I looked back at the timeframe in which this all started and found that it was right around the time I installed New Relic on the server.  So I uninstalled it, restarted IIS, and let the site go for 48 hours without it.  I didn't get a single error in that time.  So a couple hours ago I reinstalled it and sure enough I was able to duplicate the problem.

Anyway, I've removed New Relic again and all is good.  I'll notify them about this.